# push_back all contents in vector<char> to combine them as the first element of vector<string>

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to parse a string with spaces into several strings and store them into a list, which consists of strings without any space. I do not know how long the input of the string will me and I have the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> myWords;
vector<char> myBuffer;

int main() {
    string mySentence;
    getline(cin, mySentence);

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mySentence.length(); i++) {
        if (mySentence[i] != ' ') myBuffer.push_back(mySentence[i]);
        else {
            myWords.push_back(myBuffer);
            myBuffer.clear();
            j++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error in which I'm getting is at `myWords.push_back(myBuffer);`. How do I get around this?

Comment: What does you debug output say that you have you've found? I don't get what you wan't to achieve.

Comment: Also, "The error" .. would be good to know.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- [Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: *I'm trying to parse a string with spaces into several strings and store them into a list* -- This is much simpler if you used [std::istringstream](https://www.ideone.com/bPnfVM)

Comment: Sorry, I've got the solution already. It seems like I should adjust `myBuffer` to `string` type in order to `push_back` it to my vector.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you please provide me a link to what `istringstream` does?  Your solution is far more efficient, I think. I don't quite understand what `std::istringstream strm(mySentence)` annd `strm >> word` mean.

Comment: `istringstream` is like `cin` from a string. You put what you want parsed in the stream and then read it out with `>>`.

Comment: @user4581301 So the code `std::istringstream strm(mySentence)` means "Insert the contents of `mySentence` into this new variable called `strm`"? By 'reading' (I assume it's done with the code `strm >> word`, do you mean that I'm taking the strings, separated by a whitespace, and insert it into `word`?


Could you give me a short reading/link about this matter and its implementation, if possible :-)? I'd like to see more examples.

Comment: A great example is option 2 of this answer to the question [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301).

Comment: @user4581301 Is my understanding correct in regard to the above matter (my previous comment)?

Comment: Still brooding over the `error` ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo The error says:
`error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::push_back(std::vector<char>&)'`.

Comment: @WealthyPlayer My apologies. Yes.

Comment: "Get around" may not be the correct approch. What is your purpose with the push-backs? Describe how you'd like the program to work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm trying to divide a long sentence, e.g. "I am a horse" that is contained in a `string` type variable to "I", "am", "a", "horse" and insert it into a `vector<string>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to push a `std::vector<char>` where a `std::string` is expected.  So simply change the type of `myBuffer` to a `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string mySentence;
    std::getline(std::cin, mySentence);

    std::vector<std::string> myWords;
    std::string myBuffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < mySentence.length(); i++) {
        if (mySentence[i] != ' ')
            myBuffer.push_back(mySentence[i]);
        else {
            myWords.push_back(myBuffer);
            myBuffer.clear();
        }
    }

    if (!myBuffer.empty()) {
        myWords.push_back(myBuffer);
    }

    // use myWords as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, using a `std::istringstream` would be much simpler, as `operator>>` reads  whitespace-delimited values from a stream for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string mySentence;
    std::getline(std::cin, mySentence);

    std::vector<std::string> myWords;
    std::string myBuffer;

    std::istringstream iss(mySentence);
    while (iss >> myBuffer) {
        myWords.push_back(myBuffer);
    }

    // use myWords as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, let the standard library handle the reading and pushing for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::string mySentence;
    std::getline(std::cin, mySentence);

    std::vector<std::string> myWords;

    std::istringstream iss(mySentence);
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::back_inserter(myWords)
    );

    // use myWords as needed...

    return 0;
}
```